# Difficulty adding priceLevel with google places api

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-places-api, swift4

Using Google Places API I'm adding the place's website and priceLevel. I created this function:

```
func didClickWebsite(place: EClass) {
   Zone.PlaceDetails(place: place) { (place) in
        if let website = place.details?["website"] as? String, let url = URL(string: website) {
           let svc = SFSafariViewController.init(url: url)
           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func goToWebSite(_ sender: Any) {
    if let place = place, let delegate = delegate {
       delegate.didClickWebsite(place: place)
    }
}
```

That works so when I press the button, it sends me to the place's site. For the priceLevel, I'm trying to emulate the same concept. I created this in my custom tableViewCell class:

```
func update(place:EClass) {
    self.place = place
    myLabel.text = place.name
    myImage.image = nil
    myLabel2.text = place.getDescription()
    if let url = place.photos?.first?.getPhotoURL(maxWidth: maxWidht) {
        myImage.af_setImage(withURL: url)
    }

    Zone.PlaceDetails(place: place) { (place) in
        if let price = place.details?["price_level"] as? Int, let PriceLevel: Int = Int(price) {
            let o = Int(PriceLevel)
            self.myPriceLabel.text = "\(o)"          
        }
    }
}
```

I want the priceLevel to be shown in the tableview through a label, but it doesn't work. When I run the app in my tableView `myPriceLabel` remains unchanged "label". How can I fix this problem?

UPDATE

```
static func PlaceDetails(place:EClass, completion: @escaping (EClass) -> Void) {

    guard place.details == nil else {
        completion(place)
        return
    }

    var params : [String : Any]
    params = [
        "key" : AppDelegate.googlePlacesAPIKey,
        "placeid" : place.placeId,
    ]

    Alamofire.request(googlePlaceDetailsHost, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)).responseJSON { response in
        let value = response.result.value as? [String : Any]
        place.details = (value)?["result"] as? [String : Any]
        completion(place)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, this line is unnecessary: `let PriceLevel: Int = Int(price)`.  Your compiler is likely giving you a warning about this to tell you that you can't use optional binding for non-optional values.  Since you are already unwrapping `price` as an Int then there's no need to pass it into another `Int` init.  And you *definitely* don't need to be passing that into a THIRD `Int` init with the line `let o = Int(PriceLevel)`.

The next thing is that, since I assume `Zone.PlaceDetails` is a networking call you'll need to ensure your `myPriceLabel` text is being updated on the main queue.  Perhaps `PlaceDetails` executes the completion handler on the main queue already, in which case you can ignore this comment.

Finally, you are not providing a fallback option in the case where you don't get a `details` object back in your call, or the `details` doesn't have a value for the key "price_level", or the value is not an `Int`.  You could add an `else` to handle that like so:

```
Zone.PlaceDetails(place: place) { (place) in
    //Make sure your labels are being set on the main queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let price = place.details?["price_level"] as? Int {
            self.myPriceLabel.text = "\(price)"          
        } else {
            self.myPriceLabel.text = "UNKNOWN" //Or whatever you want it to say
        }
    }
}
```

If you are getting "UNKNOWN" every time I'd suggest looking into the API documentation to find out what kind of value is actually provided in that `price_level` value.  Perhaps it's actually a `Float` or a `String` or something else.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried but i'm getting "UNKNOWN" every time, i also looked in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) but i don't find something useful, the key "price_level" is correct and also the type Int, so i don't know what could be the problem

Comment: You will have to do some basic JSON debugging in that case.  You are correct in that price_level is an Int.  I'd have to see the details of your `Zone.PlaceDetails` function to know how you are getting `place.details`.  Also worth noting that the example JSON in Google Docs doesn't have price_level, so it probably doesn't exist for everything.

Comment: i edited the question if you want to give a look to my Zone.PlaceDetails

Comment: OK, that looks pretty good.  It seems like you've done everything correctly, and that the price_level just doesn't exist on the places you're looking at.  Perhaps Google isn't supporting that feature anymore, or is using it only in very limited locations?

Comment: Or if you really want to test to see what's in there, just put a `print` statement inside that placeDetails AF response.  Right after you say `place.details = (value)....` just say `print(((value)?["result"] as? [String : Any] ?? [String : Any]()).debugDescription)`

Comment: tried, you're right it seems that it does not support anymore that feature

Comment: can i ask you last thing, you know of what type is review[] ? because i saw that is an array but i don't know the type

Comment: Based on the documentation it's an array of dictionaries, so you'd write that as `[[String : Any]]`.